# node.js - listen for database changes and update them

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm running node.js code on my server to get data from mysql database.
This is my code:

```
var express   =    require("express");
var mysql     =    require('mysql');
var app       =    express();

var pool      =    mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100, //important
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'coinflip',
    debug    :  true
});

function handle_database(req,res) {

    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
        if (err) {
          connection.release();
          res.json({"code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database"});
          return;
        }  

        console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);

        connection.query("SELECT * FROM games WHERE winner=''",function(err,rows){
            connection.release();
            if(!err) {
                res.json(rows);
            }          
        });

        connection.on('error', function(err) {      
              res.json({"code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database"});
              return;    
        });
  });
}

app.get("/",function(req,res){-
        handle_database(req,res);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

It gets all data I want from database, but I want it to auto-refresh without refreshing whole site. By auto-refresh I mean if there is any change (`update`, `insert`), display them on site. 

Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't know if it's still needed.. But there is a simple libary https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-events

Comment: That went fast :D